# how to create 2d array from templated struct

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I've already asked several questions on the code below and have had a lot of help... I fairly new to C++ and just playing around with this code I actually found on here.  I'd like to create a 2d array that can then be used to call a template function taking 2 template arguments..   Code and questions/comments below.   I'd rather leave it as a pure array(not std::array) for now so I can understand what is happening.

```
class Test
{
public:
    template<int N>
    bool foo(double x, double y) { assert(false); }

    template<bool B, int N>
    double foo2(double x, double y) { assert(false); }

    template<int N, int... Ns>
    struct fn_table : fn_table < N - 1, N - 1, Ns... > {};

    template<int... Ns>
    struct fn_table < 0, Ns... >
    {
        //this expands to foo<0>,foo<1>...foo<Ns>,correct?
        static constexpr bool(*fns[])(double, double) = {foo<Ns>...};

        //how to make this part work for 2d array to include bool from foo2?
            //  Compiler gives: "parameter packs not expanded with ..."
        static constexpr bool(*fns2[][Ns])(double, double) = {foo2<Ns, Ns>...}; 
            //instead of [][Ns] and <Ns,Ns> can we explicity only create 2 rows for bool?
    };
};

template<> bool Test::foo<5>(double x, double) { return false; }

//will below work? will false be converted to match 0 from call in main?
template<> double Test::foo2<false, 1>(double x, double y) { return x; }

template<int... Ns>
constexpr bool(*Test::fn_table<0, Ns...>::fns[sizeof...(Ns)])(double, double);

//how to define for 2d fns2?
template<int... Ns>
constexpr bool(*Test::fn_table<0, Ns...>::fns2[][sizeof...(Ns)])(double, double);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int val = atoi(argv[0]);
    int val2 = atoi(argv[1]);
    Test::fn_table<5> table;
    bool b = table::fns[val];
    double d = table::fns2[0, val];
    double d = table::fns2[false, val];//does false convert to 0? 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may get you closer:

```
template<int... Ns>
struct fn_table < 0, Ns... >
{
    static constexpr double(*fns2[2][sizeof...(Ns)])(double, double) =
    { { &foo2<false, Ns>... }, { &foo2<true, Ns>... } };
```

};

There are many other problems with the program, though...

Comment: ah I see..that makes sense..   What are some of the other problems?  In  terms of compiling, it will compile if the statements referring to fns2 are removed.

Comment: looks like that will work..  I'm wondering if the bool/int conversions will work.